# Parameter to allow users to select locked cells?

Tags: vba, excel

What's the parameter to allow users to select locked cells? When you manually protect a worksheet there is an option for this, but I can't find it for VBA.

Sorry if this question has been asked but I can't find it with so many overlapping words with other results.

Comment: For questions like this you should use the Macro Recorder, and then manually do the change you want. When you go back and review the recorded macro, it will show you all the terms you need to know, and if it doesn't make sense explicitly, you can search for those terms online.

Comment: Right, totally forgot about that one.. My bad. Not used to having that 'tool'.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you that you want to keep certain cells unlocked when the worksheet is protected (so that users may select, edit, etc.) you can use:

```
Range("A1").Locked = False
```

Where `A1` can be replaced with whichever range of cells you want to leave unlocked when the sheet is protected.

Alternatively, you may be able to accomplish what you need by using:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
```

And changing `Sheet1` to whichever worksheet you want users to be able to select on.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't phrase it properly. I want them to be able to select locked cells, but not change the value of them. If you use the userinterface there is an option for this. What's the option for that when using VBA? I have WS.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True right now:

Comment: Not a problem, I added a second piece of code that might accomplish what you're asking.  I am testing on my machine right now.